# Openpyxl: Decode 'auto' color to rgb value

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to determine the color of borders set in an Excel document. I use the 'openpyxl' library (latest Version 3.0.9) and encountered a problem to extract the rgb color code when the user sets the border via the default 'auto' color.

When I extract the cell color property, I see this (in my debugger, see screenshot). None of the cell fields are set with an RGB code, the fields indicate some problem with extracting the color information. I assume this is due to the 'auto' color.

The index color probably refers to this in documentation:

## Default Color Index as per 18.8.27 of ECMA Part 4

```
COLOR_INDEX = (
    '00000000', '00FFFFFF', '00FF0000', '0000FF00', '000000FF', #0-4
    '00FFFF00', '00FF00FF', '0000FFFF', '00000000', '00FFFFFF', #5-9
    '00FF0000', '0000FF00', '000000FF', '00FFFF00', '00FF00FF', #10-14
    '0000FFFF', '00800000', '00008000', '00000080', '00808000', #15-19
    '00800080', '00008080', '00C0C0C0', '00808080', '009999FF', #20-24
    '00993366', '00FFFFCC', '00CCFFFF', '00660066', '00FF8080', #25-29
    '000066CC', '00CCCCFF', '00000080', '00FF00FF', '00FFFF00', #30-34
    '0000FFFF', '00800080', '00800000', '00008080', '000000FF', #35-39
    '0000CCFF', '00CCFFFF', '00CCFFCC', '00FFFF99', '0099CCFF', #40-44
    '00FF99CC', '00CC99FF', '00FFCC99', '003366FF', '0033CCCC', #45-49
    '0099CC00', '00FFCC00', '00FF9900', '00FF6600', '00666699', #50-54
    '00969696', '00003366', '00339966', '00003300', '00333300', #55-59
    '00993300', '00993366', '00333399', '00333333',  #60-63
)
# indices 64 and 65 are reserved for the system foreground and background colours respectively
```

The documentation says that Index 64 is reserved so there is no point in trying to access the color array (max index is 63).

Source: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html

I can be brave and deal with index 64 as black, which seems to be the eternal auto-color anyway but I am wondering if there is a proper way to decode the 'auto' color from Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System colours are set by the application. Windows defaults will be white background and black foreground. You can check the `colors` part of the styles.xml to see if these have been overriden, but really the client application gets to decide.